# Is it possible to create a filter that will be invoked once after the authentication?

Tags: apache-2.2

We use Apache HTTPD server version 2.2.
I want to create a filter that will be invoked once after the authentication.
May be I missed but I can not find it here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_filter.html

**Added**

We use Apache for the authentication (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)

May be we should create our own authorization module (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_user.html)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "invoked once after the authentication"? Are you using Apache for authentication or some other program?

Comment: We use Apache for the authentication